# How to display a span when validating a form?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my Angular application I need to display an error when the form has been submitted.
Using the following code, the  tag never show up.

- Any idea what am I doing wrong?

  ```
      <form name="addLocationForm" ng-submit="submitForm(addLocationForm.$valid)" novalidate>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input id="name"
                 type="text"
                 ng-model="locationName"
                 ng-required="true"
                 ng-minlength="4"
                 ng-maxlength="128">
          <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="addLocationForm.submitted && addLocationForm.name.$invalid">Name is required</span>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
  ```

-------------------------------------- in controller

```
   // Submit the form after all validation has occurred         
    $scope.submitForm = function (isValid) {
        // Is form valid?
        if (isValid) {
            // Create a location
            var location = {
                Id: null,
                Name: $scope.locationName
            };
            locationsService.addLocation(location).then(
                    function () {
                        alert('Saved');
                        _getLocations();
                    },
                    function (data) {
                        // Handle error
                        alert(data.data.modelState.location[0]);
                    }
                );
        }
    };
```

Comment: Input fields require a 'name' attribute to be published on the scope: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state

Answer (score 0):

I would change the folllowing:

```
  <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="submitted && addLocationForm.name.$invalid">Name is required</span>

<button type="submit" data-ng-click="submitted=true">Add</button>
```

or you can try something like that:

```
   <form name="loginForm" novalidate 
     ng-app="LoginApp" ng-controller="LoginController" ng-submit="login()">
     <div class="form-group">
       <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" 
         placeholder="Username" required ng-model="session.username" />
       <span class="help-block" 
         ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">Required</span>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" 
         placeholder="Password" required ng-model="session.password" />
       <span class="help-block" 
         ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required">Required</span>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
           value="Login" title="Login" ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid">
           <span>Login</span>
         </button>
     </div>
   </form>
```

use ng-show and you can add require, minlength, maxlength and more...

this link also can help you : http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

Comment: ok please remove addLocationForm.$valid from ng-submit="submitForm()"

Comment: you can add data-ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid" to the submit button instead, but don't use it on ng-submit, what is the error you get?

Comment: i think you also forgot to add name=login to the input, you added id but you need name, also please user the same name for the model it can help

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
        <h2>Insert a Location</h2>
        <form name="addLocationForm" ng-submit="submitForm(addLocationForm.$valid)" novalidate>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text"
                   name="name"
                   ng-model="location.name"
                   ng-minlength=3
                   ng-maxlength=20
                   ng-required="true" />
            <div class="error-container" ng-show="addLocationForm.name.$dirty && addLocationForm.name.$invalid">
                <span class="error" ng-show="addLocationForm.name.$error.required">Name is required</span>
                <span class="error" ng-show="addLocationForm.name.$error.minlength">Name has to be at least 4 characters long</span>
                <span class="error" ng-show="addLocationForm.name.$error.maxlength">Name cannot be longer than 128 characters</span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>



// Submit the form after all validation has occurred            
$scope.submitForm = function (isValid) {
    // Is form valid?
    if (isValid) {
        // Create a location
        var location = {
            Id: null,
            Name: $scope.location.name
        };
        locationsService.addLocation(location).then(
                function () {
                    alert('Saved');
                    _getLocations();
                },
                function (data) {
                    // Handle error
                    alert(data.data.modelState.location[0]);
                }
            );
    }
};
```